# How do I update GtkProgressBar in a loop?

Tags: c, gtk, progress-bar, gtk3

I can not simply call `gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction` while in a loop, because it will not take any affect until the loop ends.

If I use `gtk_main_iteration();` to force main to iterate along the call of `gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction` it works of course.. but the loop processes significantly slower.

What can I do to update the progressbar while processing in a loop?

Comment: You need to put the loop in a different thread, and then access the progress bar with `g_threads_enter()` and `g_threads_leave()`. If you could post some code, I might be able to give you an example.

Comment: @iharob What kind of code? I can send you the whole program.

Comment: I have work to do, but if you can pay for the fix, it could be done, if you want post the part that troubles you here, and I will take a look at it and try to suggest a fix, otherwise I am open to business.

Comment: I know how to use g_thread. The program I have made could be also useful. It just need some speed optimization. So I guess I am fine.

Comment: If that's all it needs it's Ok, but in a GUI it's not only about speed, using threads is mandatory for responsiveness which makes a gui application high quality, you don't like to use an application that freezes and flickers a lot, like say Windows Operating System Applications, you want a fluid simple and dynamic application, to make your work pleasant and simple.

Comment: Yes. No it is not about freezing, the call of `gtk_main_iteration();` will unfreeze the program every time it freezes. Windows is the worst environment for any sort of programs. Yes.

Comment: Anyway.. I fixed it. But without using any other threading functions other than `g_thread_new` There is no need for mutexes and stuff like that on the way I made it.

Comment: You could also have multiplexed your loop with `gdk_threads_idle_add()`. I'm not sure how performant this is, but if you need to update other parts of the GUI at the same time, this is the only way to go (as far as I know, anyway).

Comment: @andlabs gdk threads has been deprecated in gtk3

Comment: @DeltaProxy no, `gdk_threads_enter()` and `gdk_threads_leave()` have. `gdk_threads_idle_add()` has not; it's still the main way to get an idle task going *on the UI thread*. The deprecation of the other functions means you can't just force another thread to do UI stuff anymore (assuming that was even reliable in the first place).

Comment: I tried `gdk_threads_idle_add()` but nothing happened.

Answer (score -1):

I used this example to learn about progress & threads

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Simple example of a PyGTK3 application with a background thread.
'''

import random
import threading
import time

from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

APP_NAME = 'Threaded GUI Example'
TARGET = 100.0

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    '''
    The worker thread, which would normally do something more useful.

    It is important that the worker thread does not attempt to update the
    GUI. Doing so can cause crashes and weird behaviour.

    @param delegate the object to be informed of progress being made
    '''
    def __init__(self, delegate):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.counter = 0
        self.done = False

    def run(self):
        '''
        The work done by the thread.

        Overridden from threading.Thread. Sits in a loop until the done
        flag is set, updating a counter and sleeping to simulate some work.
        '''
        while True:
            if self.done:
                print 'Background thread shutting down cleanly'
                break

            # This counter is only updated by one thread, so probably
            # doesn't need a lock, but it needs thinking about.
            self.counter = self.counter + 1 if self.counter < TARGET else 0

            # Ask the main thread to update the GUI when it has time.
            GObject.idle_add(self.delegate.update_progress)

            # Sleep for a little bit ...
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.01, 0.1))


class Main(Gtk.Window):
    '''
    The main application GUI running in the main thread.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title=APP_NAME)
        self.set_size_request(500, 300)

        # Lay out the GUI.
        vbox = Gtk.VBox(False, 0)

        # Set up a progress bar to show how the worker is progressing.
        self.progress_bar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        vbox.pack_start(self.progress_bar, False, False, 0)




        # Set up a text view to show the responsiveness of the GUI.
        scroller = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        textview = Gtk.TextView()
        textview.get_buffer().set_text(
            'The counting is going on in the worker thread with the GUI '\
            'handling updates in the idle loop. You can type in the text '\
            'view or resize the window and it should be responsive.\n\n'
        )
        textview.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD)
        scroller.add(textview)
        vbox.pack_start(scroller, True, True, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

        # Connect the destroy event so that we can set the done flag and
        # terminate the worker cleanly.
        self.connect("destroy", self.on_quit)

        # Kick off the background thread.
        self.worker = WorkerThread(self)
        self.worker.start()

    def update_progress(self):
        '''
        Update the progress bar.

        The method called on request in the idle loop to update the GUI. The
        worker requests the update using GObject.idle_add()
        @return True to repeat indefinitely, False for a single invocation
        '''
        progress = self.worker.counter / TARGET
        self.progress_bar.set_fraction(progress)
        self.set_title('{} ({}%)'.format(APP_NAME, progress * 100))
        return False

    def on_quit(self, widget):
        '''
        Quit the application

        Handler called when the application is about to quit. Set the done
        flag so that the worker quits cleanly, then quit.
        '''
        self.worker.done = True
        Gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The background thread will not run concurrently against the main
    # thread without the threads_init() call:
    GObject.threads_init()
    Main()
    Gtk.main()
```